# Very simple map implemention in C (for caching purpose)?

Tags: c, dictionary, code-snippets, code-reuse

I have a program that read urls in a file and does a `gethostbyname()` on each URL host. This call is quite consuming. I want to cache them.

Is there a very simple map-base code snippet in C out there that I could use to do the caching? (I just don't want to reinvent the wheel).

It has to have the following points :

- Open-source with a **permissive license** (think BSD or public domain).
- **Very** simple : ideally less than 100 LOC
- Keys are `char*` and values `void*`. No need to copy them.
- No real need to implement `remove()`, but `contains()` is either needed or `put()` should replace the value.

PS: I tagged it *homework*, since it could be. I'm just being *very* lazy and do want to avoid all the common pitfalls I could encounter while reimplementing.

Comment: @Sinan & Meredith : I accepted the code snipped since it was **exactly** what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a very simple and naive one

- Fixed bucket size
- No delete operation
- inserts replaces the key and value, and can optionally free them

:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NR_BUCKETS 1024

struct StrHashNode {
    char *key;
    void *value;
    struct StrHashNode *next;

};

struct StrHashTable {
    struct StrHashNode *buckets[NR_BUCKETS];
    void (*free_key)(char *);
    void (*free_value)(void*);
    unsigned int (*hash)(const char *key);
    int (*cmp)(const char *first,const char *second);
};

void *get(struct StrHashTable *table,const char *key)
{
    unsigned int bucket = table->hash(key)%NR_BUCKETS;
    struct StrHashNode *node;
    node = table->buckets[bucket];
    while(node) {
        if(table->cmp(key,node->key) == 0)
            return node->value;
        node = node->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
int insert(struct StrHashTable *table,char *key,void *value)
{
    unsigned int bucket = table->hash(key)%NR_BUCKETS;
    struct StrHashNode **tmp;
    struct StrHashNode *node ;

    tmp = &table->buckets[bucket];
    while(*tmp) {
        if(table->cmp(key,(*tmp)->key) == 0)
            break;
        tmp = &(*tmp)->next;
    }
    if(*tmp) {
        if(table->free_key != NULL)
            table->free_key((*tmp)->key);
        if(table->free_value != NULL)
            table->free_value((*tmp)->value);
        node = *tmp;
    } else {
        node = malloc(sizeof *node);
        if(node == NULL)
            return -1;
        node->next = NULL;
        *tmp = node;
    }
    node->key = key;
    node->value = value;

    return 0;
}

unsigned int foo_strhash(const char *str)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for(; *str; str++)
        hash = 31*hash + *str;
    return hash;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct StrHashTable tbl = {{0},NULL,NULL,foo_strhash,strcmp};

    insert(&tbl,"Test","TestValue");
    insert(&tbl,"Test2","TestValue2");
    puts(get(&tbl,"Test"));
    insert(&tbl,"Test","TestValueReplaced");
    puts(get(&tbl,"Test"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: Exactly what I was searching for. I edited the code a little to cope with correct const-ness (key & value). Now my apps starts in less than a sec, instead of the 2 minutes @ 100% cpu :-)

Answer (score 6):

[Christoper Clark's hashtable implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20090906050400/http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk:80/%7Ecwc22/hashtable/) is very straightforward. It is more than 100 lines, but not by much.

Clark's code seems to have made its way into [Google's Conccurrency Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-concurrency-library/source/browse/samples/dedup/hashtable.c) as a parallelization example.

Comment: The link in this link-only answer is dead.

Comment: @vaultah Pointed the link to `archive.org`. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` in C++ is a red-black tree under the hood; what about using [an existing red-black tree implementation in C](http://www.mit.edu/~emin/source_code/red_black_tree/index.html)? The one I linked is more like 700 LOC, but it's pretty well commented and looks sane from the cursory glance I took at it. You can probably find others; this one was the first hit on Google for "C red-black tree".

If you're not picky about performance you could also use an unbalanced binary tree or a min-heap or something like that. With a balanced binary tree, you're guaranteed O(log n) lookup; with an unbalanced tree the worst case for lookup is O(n) (for the pathological case where nodes are inserted in-order, so you end up with one really long branch that acts like a linked-list), but (if my rusty memory is correct) the average case is still O(log n).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using following implemntation

[clib](http://code.google.com/p/cstl/source/browse/src/c_map.c)

Comment: Thanks, It is still work in progress. Hoping to finish in another 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

[memcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients)?

Not a code snippet, but a high performance distributed caching engine.

Comment: -1: I do want to avoid a syscall (`gethostbyname()`), so I don't really think that memcached fits the bill here.

Answer (score 1):

Not lazy, deeply sensible to avoid writing this stuff.

How's this [library](http://www.ioplex.com/~miallen/libmba/) never used it myself but it seems to claim to do what you ask for.

Comment: The library seems interesting, but the last update to the website was 2005. It would be OK for a few code lines, but a little too old for a full blown library.

Comment: Well, fundamental algorithms well implemented should not become dated. I would have no concern about using 4 year old libraries of this kind - assuming that they actually worked in the first place. If you ahve the code, then maintenance should not be too much of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Dave Hanson's [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/cii/) includes a nice hash table, as well as many other useful modules.  The hash table clocks in at 150 lines, but that's including memory management, a higher-order mapping function, and conversion to array. The software is free, and the book is worth buying.

Answer (score 0):

Found an implementation here : [c](http://www.w3.org/2001/06/blindfold/api/hashmap_8c-source.html) file  and [h](http://www.w3.org/2001/06/blindfold/api/hashmap_8h-source.html) file that's fairly close to what you asked. W3C license